# Notation: why are categories enriched over $\mathcal V$?

Tags: category-theory, notation, monoidal-categories, enriched-category-theory

In most references about enriched categories, $(\mathcal V, \otimes)$ is supposed to be a monoidal category and then $\mathcal V$-enriched categories are defined.

Why is the letter $\mathcal V$ used for a monoidal category?

Comment: I'm not sure, but one of the basic examples of a monoidal category is $\mathcal{V}= k-\mathbf{Vect}$ for some field $k$ : the $V$ would then be here for "vector" or "vector space"

Comment: Perhaps originating from a term like *virtual sets* (just a guess).